# Counting currency from NSDictionary objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnumberformatter, nsenumerator

The basic idea is to iterate through a directory full of .plists which have NSDictionary objects that contain a monetary value.

### Question

**How can I iterate through all of the directory contents and extract all the "`Current Value`" objects and add them together to get a total amount?**

### Example

```
NSArray * itemList = [MANAGER contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",INVENTORY_PATH] error:nil];
for ( NSString * item in itemList )
{
    NSDictionary * currentItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",INVENTORY_PATH, item]];

    float monetaries = [[currentItem objectForKey:@"Current Value"] floatValue];

    NSLog(@"Current Value: %.2f",monetaries);       
}
```

### Current output

```
2012-05-06 22:11:33.583 WrightsCS[3151:15803] Current Value: 350.99
2012-05-06 22:11:33.584 WrightsCS[3151:15803] Current Value: 321.54
```

### Desired output

```
2012-05-06 22:11:33.584 WrightsCS[3151:15803] Total Value: 672.53
```

### Solution

```
float total = 0.0f ;
float monetaries = 0.0f;

NSArray * itemList = [MANAGER contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",INVENTORY_PATH] error:nil];
for ( NSString * item in itemList )
{
    NSDictionary * currentItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",INVENTORY_PATH, item]];

    monetaries = [[currentItem objectForKey:@"Current Value"] floatValue];
    total += monetaries ;     

    NSLog(@"Current Value: %.2f",monetaries);  
}    

NSLog(@"Total Value: %.2f",total);
```

### Solution Output

```
2012-05-06 22:26:05.460 WrightsCS[3205:15803] Current Value: 350.99
2012-05-06 22:26:05.462 WrightsCS[3205:15803] Current Value: 321.54
2012-05-06 22:26:05.462 WrightsCS[3205:15803] Total Value: 672.53
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you just keep a running total or did I miss it?

```
NSArray * itemList = [MANAGER contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",INVENTORY_PATH] error:nil];

float total = 0.0f ;
for ( NSString * item in itemList )
{
    NSDictionary * currentItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",INVENTORY_PATH, item]];

    float monetaries = [[currentItem objectForKey:@"Current Value"] floatValue];
    total += monetaries ;
//    NSLog(@"Current Value: %.2f",monetaries);       
} 

NSLog(@"Total Value: %.2f",monetaries);
```

Comment: Also instead of using `-stringWithFormat:` to construct the path I think it's more correct to use `-stringByAddingPathComponent:`